# SQL to get some groups and keep the order

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have an example data as below.

```
+---------+------------+--------+
| user id |   sequence | Action |
|---------|------------|--------|
| 12345   |    1       | Run    |
| 12345   |    2       | Sit    |
| 12345   |    3       | Sit    |
| 12345   |    4       | Run    |
| 12345   |    5       | Run    |
| 12345   |    6       | Sit    |
+---------+------------+--------+
```

Now I'd like the result should be like this:

```
+---------+---------+
| user id |  Action |
|---------|---------|
| 12345   |  Run    |
| 12345   |  Sit    |
| 12345   |  Run    |
| 12345   |  Sit    |
+---------+---------+
```

The row with sequence #2 and #3 should be merged, #4 and #5 should be merged.
I use 'group by Action' will get answer like the following table, but it isn't what I want:

```
+---------+---------+
| user id |  Action |
|---------|---------|
| 12345   |  Run    |
| 12345   |  Sit    |
+---------+---------+
```

How can I implement SQL(I use Google Bigquery)?

Thanks a million!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below  for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(dup) FROM (
  SELECT *, action = LAG(action, 1, '') OVER(PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY sequence) AS dup
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE NOT dup
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row user_id sequence    action   
1   12345   1           Run  
2   12345   2           Sit  
3   12345   4           Run  
4   12345   6           Sit
```

Comment: It's amazing to me! Thanks for promptly providing answer!

Comment: @LucasLee - Consider also voting up the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions: the idea is to compare the action on each row to the "previous" action, and filter on the rows where the value changes:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lag(action) over(partition by user_id order by sequence) lag_action
    from mytable t
) t
where action <> lag_action or lag_action is null
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful.